# Apache Flink: How can I compute windows with local pre-aggregation?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a `DataStream` and need to compute a window aggregation on it. When I perform a regular window aggregation, the network IO is very high.
So, I'd like to perform local pre-aggregation to decrease the network IO.

I wonder if it is possible to pre-aggregate locally on the task managers (i.e., before shuffling the records) and then perform the full aggregate. Is this possible with Flink's DataStream API?

My code is:

```
DataStream<String> dataIn = .... 
dataIn
  .map().filter().assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()
  .keyBy().window().fold()
```

Answer (score 1):

The current release of Flink (Flink 1.4.0, Dec 2017) does not feature built-in support for pre-aggregations. However, there are efforts on the way to add this for the next release (1.5.0), see [FLINK-7561](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7561).

You can implement a pre-aggregation operation based on a [`ProcessFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#the-processfunction). The `ProcessFunction` could keep the pre-aggregates in a `HashMap` (of fixed size) in memory and register timers event-time and processing-time) to periodically emit the pre-aggregates. The state (i.e., content of the `HashMap`) should be persisted in [managed operator state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/state/state.html#operator-state) to prevent data loss in case of a failure. When setting the timers, you need to respect the window boundaries.

Please note that `FoldFunction` has been deprecated and should be replaced by [`AggregateFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#aggregatefunction).